# Proper name of a curve from "Vanishing Surfaces"

Tags: surfaces, projective-geometry

My question is maybe more about linguistics than maths... So, if you have a 3D surface that vanishes as a curve when projected on a 2D-plane (e.g. an axisymmetric surface projected to the r-Z plane). How would you call that curve? 
It doesn't need to be an agreed term, but something that describes it and can be remembered.

Thanks!